# InetAddress.getAddress() always returns a null, but somehow still works

Tags: java, network-programming, inetaddress

I have a String IP address that I need to convert to a byte array. For this, I used `InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress()`, and it all works great.

However, when I looked at the code of `InetAddress.getAddress()`, it looks like this:

```
public byte[] getAddress() {
    return null;
}
```

There is absolutely no operation being done here - however, I am still getting a byte array back, with the corerect values too. How is this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you use to get the address, `InetAddress.getByName` returns a subclass: either an `Inet4Address` or an `Inet6Address`. These 2 subclasses have the `getAddress` method implemented to return something useful.

Answer (score 1):

I will add this to further @assylias's answer.

If you look through the source code of `InetAddress.getByName` you will notice that all it really does, is call down into `InetAddress.getAllByName`. If you look at the source for **that** method, you will see the following towards the end:

```
InetAddress[] ret = new InetAddress[1];

if(addr != null) {
    if (addr.length == Inet4Address.INADDRSZ) {
        ret[0] = new Inet4Address(null, addr);
    } else {
        if (ifname != null) {
            ret[0] = new Inet6Address(null, addr, ifname);
        } else {
            ret[0] = new Inet6Address(null, addr, numericZone);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

There you can see that `InetAddress.getAllByName` attempts to determine what version of IP that the address is formatted as. It then instanciates an `Inet4/6Address` Object based on the format of your input string.

Therefore, because you are getting either `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address`, and they both have full implementations of `getAddress`, you never really call the `InetAddress.getAddress` method.